# Printing localReport with only printer selection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, reportviewer, localreport

How can I print a LocalReport without preview but with a printer selection window?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own Form with a printer selection. Bind the installed printers to a combobox or something using the `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings` class

```
    foreach (string s in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
    {
      liste.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

Then you can create your report with this code (make sure your reports build action is set to embedded resource)

```
LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("your data source name",DataTableGoesHere);
        report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourNameSpace.YourReportName.rdlc";
```

Then follow these instructions here to print a localreport: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report.aspx

Make sure you somehow pass the variable of the printer to use into the printing class. The printers name must be set:

```
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "installed printer chosen from combo goes here";
```